# MVC Where to store all models

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have several models/objects. I would store them now in one/several lists (in a separate class). Is this storage class part of the model or part of the controller? Or where would you store your objects?

Comment: `where would you store your objects` - some people keep stuff on their basement, some on their attic.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I'd like to implement mvc in my app and try to follow the architecture. Now I don't exactly now if the storage job is part of the controller or the model. I find it's easier if its part of the controller, but I'm not sure if this the idea of mvc

Comment: Storage is no part of a controller or model. It's part of some persistence layer. Don't think in boxes to much. There is more to an application then just following a MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I'm referencing ASP.NET MVC (2 and up). I'm not aware if the same rules apply to other frameworks or not.

In all MVC projects I worked in, each item has its own folder. Models go into the *Models* folder, controllers in the *Controllers* folder, etc.
If I recall correctly, ASP.Net MVC requires a certain folder structure in some scenarios because it automatically looks for the corresponding item in a fixed set of folders.

So you should order the items by their function (Model, Controller, View). Keep in mind that you should use the same name for controllers, models and views where possible (AccountModel, AccountController, and the Views should be placed in */Views/**Account**/* or */Views/**Shared**/* if they are reusable).

That's what I was always told, at least.